ROS2 pointcloud_to_laserscan not displayed in Rviz
When I echo the /scan topic I get the following output:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 697
    nanosec: 434000000
  frame_id: camera_depth_frame
angle_min: -3.141590118408203
angle_max: 3.141590118408203
angle_increment: 0.017453299835324287
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.032999999821186066
range_min: 0.009999999776482582
range_max: 10.0
ranges:
- 0.04251193627715111
- 0.020907405763864517
- 0.015148443169891834
- 0.01083229947835207
- 0.02530861459672451
- 0.021005339920520782
- 0.01814142055809498
- 0.016711711883544922
- 0.013859163969755173
- 0.021200956776738167
- 0.012437913566827774
- 0.011021748185157776
- 0.016957463696599007
- 0.015552569180727005
- 0.01415487565100193
- 0.018702900037169456
- 0.01276675146073103
- 0.021873297169804573
- 0.011391705833375454
- 0.019140686839818954
- 0.01458748709410429
- 0.010035124607384205
- 0.013244942761957645
- 0.016458747908473015
- 0.02289084531366825
- 0.011925323866307735
- 0.03445889428257942
- 0.013856985606253147
- 0.010637175291776657
- 0.019029982388019562
- 0.012601776979863644
- 0.017790116369724274
- 0.014585992321372032
- 0.019777551293373108
- 0.011390537954866886
- 0.018587764352560043
- 0.01339939795434475
- 0.01541533600538969
- 0.01743580587208271
- 0.010238896124064922
- 0.012267310172319412
- 0.01632969081401825
- 0.020395275205373764
- 0.030562208965420723
- 0.011206273920834064
- 0.059008754789829254
- 0.030560756102204323
- 0.020394306629896164
- 0.01632891409099102
- 0.012266728095710278
- 0.010238408111035824
- 0.017434146255254745
- 0.015413868241012096
- 0.013398122042417526
- 0.018585113808512688
- 0.011389454826712608
- 0.01977379061281681
- 0.014583911746740341
- 0.01778673194348812
- 0.012599978595972061
- 0.01902545802295208
- 0.010635657235980034
- 0.01385434903204441
- 0.03444088250398636
- 0.011923055164515972
- 0.022882141172885895
- 0.016454052180051804
- 0.013241793029010296
- 0.010033216327428818
- 0.014583324082195759
- 0.01913340762257576
- 0.011388996616005898
- 0.021862899884581566
- 0.012763109058141708
- 0.01869489811360836
- 0.014150163158774376
- 0.015546654351055622
- 0.016950206831097603
- 0.011018604040145874
- 0.012433773837983608
- 0.02118886075913906
- 0.013853892683982849
- 0.016703767701983452
- 0.018131932243704796
- 0.02099236100912094
- 0.025289366021752357
- 0.010828692466020584
- 0.015141241252422333
- 0.02089349366724491
- 0.042453374713659286
- 0.04245368391275406
- 0.020893648266792297
- 0.015141352079808712
- 0.010828771628439426
- 0.02528992109000683
- 0.0209928248077631
- 0.01813233271241188
- 0.01670413464307785
- 0.013854198157787323
- 0.02118963748216629
- 0.01243404671549797
- 0.011018846184015274
- 0.016950827091932297
- 0.015547223389148712
- 0.014150680974125862
- 0.018695855513215065
- 0.01276357565075159
- 0.02186433970928192
- 0.011389413848519325
- 0.01913466863334179
- 0.014584071934223175
- 0.01003358419984579
- 0.013242471031844616
- 0.016455134376883507
- 0.022884318605065346
- 0.011923665180802345
- 0.03444617614150047
- 0.01385526079684496
- 0.010636202991008759
- 0.019027268514037132
- 0.012600808404386044
- 0.017788425087928772
- 0.014585086144506931
- 0.019775960594415665
- 0.011390204541385174
- 0.018587153404951096
- 0.013399201445281506
- 0.01541533600538969
- '...'
intensities: []

However, I am not able to visualize it in Rviz
I can see the pointcloud data but not the laser scan data.
Thanks for the help!

did you check your Fixed Frame under Global Options? Try setting it to camera_depth_frame and see if anything is visible?

I changed Fixed Frame from base_link to camera_depth_frame. It just flips my robot. I still don't see the laser scan data

I know this might be a silly question, but did you make sure you have added the correct display type to RViz? As in, LaserScan, and update the the Topic slot with the name of your topic?
The following is a simple code I ran and managed to get some visualization to happen as such: https://qtext.io/24x0

Yup, I added LaserScan and updated the topic. Still nothing shown on Rviz
